# Docker service running in Ubuntu as part of WSL on my Windws 10 machine ; high RAM usage

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

just a quick question.

I've used Docker on both a t2.micro EC2 instance running Amazon Linux (which only has 1.0Gb of RAM), as well as through the Ubuntu terminal on my Windows 10 machine. Why does the Vmmem process on my Windows machine still exist and takes up at least 1.5Gb of RAM everytime I start up Ubuntu (even if I stop Docker) on it?

Even if I start the Docker service directly through Ubuntu's terminal (`sudo service Docker start *`) , why is there a Vmmem process in Task Manager that takes up so much RAM like when I start Docker Desktop on Windows (start the Docker Desktop program on Windows -> Windows Powershell -> `Docker container start`).

Shouldn't there be no need for a VM if I start Docker directly in Ubuntu as opposed through Docker Desktop? If not, I would rather continue starting containers through Powershell as opposed to going through the hassle of doing it through the Ubuntu terminal.